Can't edit the category by id, after creating the category on the same modal by one Upsert Action in Asp.net MVC
The problem is after successful creation, when I hover the Edit button, the link is correctly showing but when I click on the Edit button it is showing Add New Category that means create feature, instead of showing the category name which I want to change. How to solve this problem? I want to edit the category on the same modal when I click on the edit button instead of creating.
In Index.cshtml:
@model IEnumerable<Category>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Categories Data</h5>
            <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Upsert" class="btn btn-primary" style="box-shadow: none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#categoryModal">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> &nbsp;Add Category
            </a>

            <!-- Modal for Create/Update Category -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="categoryModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="categoryModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Upsert" method="post">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="categoryModalLabel">
                                    @if (TempData["CategoryId"] != null)
                                    {
                                        <span>Edit Category</span>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <span>Add New Category</span>
                                    }
                                </h5>
                                <button type="button" style="box-shadow: none" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <!-- Hidden Field for Id -->
                                <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="@(TempData["CategoryId"] ?? Guid.Empty.ToString())" />


                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="CategoryName" class="form-label fw-bold ms-1">Category Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CategoryName" name="CategoryName"
                                           value="@TempData["CategoryName"]" required placeholder="Category Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Dismiss</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th>S/N</th>
                        <th>Category Name</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{
                        int index = 1;
                    }
                    @foreach (var category in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@index</td>
                            <td>@category.CategoryName</td>
                            <td>@category.CreatedAt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Upsert" asp-route-id="@category.Id"
                                   class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#categoryModal">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        index++;
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

In CategoryController:
// GET: Upsert action to prepare the modal for edit or creation
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Upsert(Guid? id)
{
    Category category = new Category();
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        category = _unitOfWork.Category.Get(c => c.Id == id.Value);
        if (category == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }

    // Store the retrieved category or new category in TempData
    TempData["CategoryId"] = category.Id;
    TempData["CategoryName"] = category.CategoryName;

    // Redirect to Index to open the modal with the data
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}


This is likely due to caching. Using TempData for the current edited item also isn't a great option.
Consider having a wrapping model that contains you collection of results along with an Category? EditingCategory for the currently editing.
public class CategoryIndexViewModel
{
    public Category? EditingCategory { get; set;} = null;
    public ICollection<Category> Results { get; set; } = [];
}

... then set up your Index with an optional int? Id which if present will load that EditingCategory into the Model to bind your edit controls to. This way your URL would be something like: "/Category/Index" for the "nothing selected" scenario, where hitting the Edit button on Category ID aaaa-bbbb-ccccc... would go to a URL "/Category/Index?aaaa-bbbb-ccccc..." making it clear to the server/browser that is a different page/content.  Rather than an "Upsert" GET which redirects to "Index", the edit hyperlink merely directs to Index with the selected ID:
<a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@category.Id" ...

Normally though I would be considering AJAX calls, where the client-side JS handles the link action and will dynamically set the content of a modal and show it, handling updates and refreshes asynchronously via AJAX as well. That would involve an anchor href set to "#" with a click event bound to kick off my asynchronous GET fetch from the server, returning a response with data to compose a view or view engine rendered HTML. That then goes into the modal content <div> and the modal is shown. This is more responsive than re-directs loading entire pages again and running foul of caching optimizations in the browser.
